# Coloco uma imagem no meu link com bootstrap, e a imagem não carrega de jeito nenhum... Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/blog">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQfa.png" width="30" height="30" alt="" loading="lazy">
    </a>
</nav>
```

Ta aí o código, ja tentei colocar um botão, não vai, não chega nem a aparecer um espaço clicável na tela...

Comment: O endereço da imagem deve estar errado. Coloca o endereço absoluto. Se mesmo assim o erro continuar deve ser proveniente de outra parte do código que não está na postagem.

Comment: Tentei colocar o caminho absoluto e ainda nada... Pode ter algo haver com a versão do Bootstrap? Por que eu não sei o que pode haver de errado com o resto do código

Comment: então tem que mostrar o código pra gente tentar ver o que está provocando o erro.

Comment: posta o código completo ai pra gente ver

Answer (score 0):

> Lazy loading é um padrão de projeto de software, comumente utilizado
> em linguagens de programação, para adiar a inicialização de um objeto
> até o ponto em que ele é necessário. Isso pode contribuir para a
> eficiência no funcionamento de um programa, se utilizado
> adequadamente. Wikipédia

Por que você quer colocar carregamento preguiçoso na sua logo se ela será a primeira a aparecer? isso não faz sentido e não foi criado para isso, agora que a Microsoft acabou com o edge e foi para o chromium, você pode usar a imagem no formato `.webp` que é mais leve e resolverá o seu problema de baixo desempenho.
Retire `loading="lazy"` que irá funcionar, além disso, escreva algo no atributo alt="" para você saber quando o link da imagem não está funcionando

```
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvQfa.png" width="30" height="30" alt="imag">
```